# Concatenating name of file and opening it

Tags: c

I need to move from the directory I am working on and then verify if a `.txt` file exists or not. The name of the `.txt` file is the `int key` value received as an argument.

What I tried to do was cast the `int` value into `char` and then append `.txt`. Then use this new string to try and open the file.

However, even if the file does exist within the directory, I still get "File doesnt exist".

What do I need to change in order for it to work?

```
    char k[10];
    char app[4] = ".txt";
    int status;

    // Change directory where we work.
    if(chdir("txtFiles") == -1){
        perror("Error while changing directories.");
        return -1;
    }

    // Convert key to string.
    snprintf(k, 10, "%d", key);
    strncat(k, app, 4);
    printf("%s\n", k);

    // Open the file.
    if((status = open(k, O_RDONLY)) == -1){
        printf("File DOESNT exist.\n");
    } else {
        printf("File exists.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for me your code says 'file does not exist' once I fixed the length of app

Comment: @pm100 My bad, it does say "file doesnt exist", just edited it.

Comment: ok - then the fix suggested below is what you need. Also check errno to make sure it realy is 'file doesnt eist' and not something like 'permission denied'

Comment: When the whole code is shown (the `int main(…)` line was hidden after the triple back-ticks before), then one of the main problems is that you've shown a wholly non-standard and unsupported variant signature for `main()`.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/15168) for the details of what is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app` is too short to accommodate `".txt"`. It has to be `char app[5] = ".txt"` (or, better, `char app[] = ".txt";` — computers are good at counting).

You can do this much more easily in one snprintf call:

```
    snprintf(k, 10, "%d.txt", key);
```

or if the extension is not always the same

```
    snprintf(k, 10, "%d%s", key, app);
```

`strncat` is not needed anymore.

Comment: does not answer the question tho

Comment: 1) Probably best to point out the cause of the problem with the `strncat` (and the sizing of `app`), 2) The second argument should be `10`, not `9` (`snprintf`, unlike some of the others, includes the terminating NUL in the count) and 3) They likely need to increase the size of `k` (unless `key` is guaranteed to be pretty small, the limit to nine characters of actual filename means any number with six digits or more won't fit, and the `.txt` will get truncated).

Comment: @pm100 it is UB. Hard to say what else was affected.